# Pass object to controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page where I display a list of products. When the user clicks on a product I show the product details in another page. This is a part of my routing configuration:

```
  when('/products', {
        templateUrl: 'views/products.html',
        controller: 'ProductListCtrl'
  }).
  when('/products'/:productId', {
         templateUrl: 'views/product-details.html',
         controller: 'ProductDetailsCtrl'
  }).
```

As you can see I can only pass `productId` (which I retrieve using `$routeParams`) as parameter, which means I need to make another AJAX call to get information about product. But I already have this data on the `products` page.

So my question is: can I pass a whole `Product` object to `ProductDetailsCtrl` instead of just passing `productId`?

Comment: If you don't want to go back to the server, you'll have to use something like a service to store the product(s) before redirecting, and then retrieve it on the next page. At that point, you don't need to pass the productId

Comment: You can configure `$http` or `$resource` service to cache data: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching

Comment: @MyTitle please check sharedProperties service i suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Product service. In the ProductListCtrl the service would make the http calls and cache the results. The ProductDetailsCtrl would also use Product service. Your service can then return a product from the cache instead of making another http request.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use shared properties service and pass elements between controllers:

```
.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var item = null;
    return {
        getItem: function () {
            return item;
        },
        setItem: function(value) {
            item = value;
        }
    }});
```

Then before you move to controller you use:

```
sharedProperties.setItem(your-item);
```

and after you load the new controller you use:

```
var model = sharedProperties.getItem();
```

Comment: Why did you suggest using `localStorage`? I think it isn't neccessary for this case and might polute the storage with no reason.

Comment: @runTarm thanks for pointing it out, i got confused with another question, here is the service i wanted to post.

Comment: Your example should be a factory given how you've implemented it (not a service)

Answer (score 0):

To actually pass an object into the controller you should use the resolve property. In the end you will have to use your service to retrieve the object. But you will get a more loosely coupled solution by not having to pass the object the service and then back to a controller.  Consider the following example:

```
 $routeProvider
   .when('/product/:productId', {
   templateUrl: 'product-details.html',
   controller: 'ProductDetailsController',
   resolve: {
      product: productService.getProductById($routeParams.productId);
   }
 });

 productApp.controller("ProductDetailsController", function($scope, product) {
   $scope.product = product;
 });
```

You can read more about it at the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).